How to write MySQL commant in terminal?
i have recently install MySQL using
sudo apt install mysql-server from ubuntu.com (https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install-and-configure-a-mysql-server) but I don'tknow how to execute my sql command.

This question is similar to: How to run mysql client. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You need a MySQL client for this. I don't remember if it gets installed automatically with the server, probably yes - if not, you need to install it additionally. Then you have to run it with mysql -u username -p (if connecting to local server, if the server is on another computer you need to add -h address), enter your MySQL password and you can type MySQL commands.
